# Js function that returns a matching letter from 2 strings

Tags: javascript

Function that returns the first letter that is present in both strings that a user submits via 
    an input type text, the strings are separated with a comma. For example:aaaaa,bbbbba--> the matching letter is 'a'because is present in both strings
Sorry for some italian names but i code in italian

I'm not sure how to continue, i have a for to go throught both strings, but i'm not sure if it's correct

```js
function Ripetizione() {
  var rip = document.getElementById("string").value;
  if (rip.indexOf(",") == -1) { //check to see if the comma is not present
    alert("Non c'è nessuna virgola");
    return;
  }

  var stringa1 = rip.substr(0, rip.indexOf(",")); //this is the string1 before the comma
  var stringa2 = rip.substr(rip.indexOf(",") + 1, rip.length - (stringa1.length + 1)); //this is the second string after the comma

  for (i = 0; i <= stringa1.length; i++) { //for cycle to count the elements of the first string


  }


  for (k = 0; i <= stringa2.lenght; k++) { //same for the string2

  }
}

Ripetizione()
```

Comment: If the input was "ab,ba", what should the output be?  "a" or "b"?

Comment: "b" because in the second string appears in the first position

Comment: @Rogi in my answer I am returning a blank string when nothing matches.

Answer (score 2):

You need not loop the second string.. Just check for index of the element => 0 , while looping through each element of first string part. And return the value..

Answer (score 2):

Always prefer functional over imperative programming.Use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
function getCommonLetter(str){
const [stringA, stringB]=str.split(',');
return Array.from(stringB).find(val => stringA.includes(val));
}

console.log(getCommonLetter('ab,ba'))
console.log(getCommonLetter('ads,bsd'))
console.log(getCommonLetter('aaa,bbc'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Ripetizione() { 
    var rip=document.getElementById("string").value;
    if (rip.indexOf(",")==-1){
        alert("Non c'è nessuna virgola");
        return;
    }

    var stringa1=rip.substr(0,rip.indexOf(","));
    var stringa2=rip.substr(rip.indexOf(",")+1,rip.length-(stringa1.length+1));

    return search(stringa1, stringa2);
}

function search(a, b){
    for(var i=0; i<a.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<b.length;j++){
            if(a[i] == b[j]){
                return a[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, glad to see that my idea wasn't wrong after all thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and check for the presence of the matching chars using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

The idea is to convert the strings into an array of string using [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) then use the `reduce` function to match and accumulate the matched characters.

```js
//returns the matching chars as an array
function Ripetizione(rip) { 
  //let rip=document.getElementById("string").value;
  let strs = rip.split(",");
  if (strs.length !== 2){ //check to see if the comma is not present
      alert("Non c'è nessuna virgola");
      return;
  }
  //converting strings to array to use reduce
  let strOne = Array.from(strs[0]), strTwo = strs[1];
  return strOne.reduce((acc,alpha)=> {
    return !acc.includes(alpha) && strTwo.includes(alpha)?[alpha,...acc]:acc;
    },[]).slice(0,1).toString();
}
console.log(Ripetizione("aaaaaab,bbbbba"));
console.log(Ripetizione("aaaaaa,bbbbba"));
console.log(Ripetizione("acccaaaa,bbbbba"));
console.log(Ripetizione("acccaaaa,bbbbcba"));
console.log(Ripetizione("dddddddd,bbbbba")); //return blank string
console.log(Ripetizione("ab,ba"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
         function Ripetizione() {
var rip = document.getElementById("string").value;
if (rip.indexOf(",") == -1) { //check to see if the comma is not present
    alert("Non c'è nessuna virgola");
    return;
}

var stringa1 = rip.substr(0, rip.indexOf(",")); //this is the string1 before the comma
var stringa2 = rip.substr(rip.indexOf(",") + 1, rip.length - (stringa1.length + 1)); //this is the second string after the comma

if (stringa1.length <= stringa2.length) {
    stringa2 = stringa2.split('')
    stringa1 = stringa1.split('')

    for (i = 0; i <= stringa2.length; i++) { //for cycle to count the elements of the first string
        if (stringa1.includes(stringa2[i])) {
                console.log(stringa2[i]);
          
        }

    }
} else if (stringa1.length >= stringa2.length) {
    stringa1 = stringa1.split('')
    stringa2 = stringa2.split('')
    for (i = 0; i <= stringa1.length; i++) { //for cycle to count the elements of the first string
        if (stringa2.includes(stringa1[i])) {
                console.log(stringa1[i]);
            
        }
    }
}
}
```

```html
<input id="string" type="text">
|<button id="ok" onclick="Ripetizione()">done</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following demo binds the change event to input. When a user enters text in input then clicks outside of input the function is called. The function uses `split()` and `filter()` and displays the result in an output. The function also removes any spaces and reports if there are no matches as well.

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
var str = document.getElementById("string");

// This is an Event Handler
function ripZ(e) {
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var rip = this.value;
  if (rip.indexOf(",") === -1) {
    result.value = "Separate the two strings with a comma (no spaces).";
    return;
  }

  // If there's a space remove it
  var rip = rip.replace(/\s/g, '');

  // Split the string at the comma making an array of two strings
  var array = rip.split(',');

  /*
  Take each string and split them at each letter.
  Now there's two arrays of letters
  */
  var first = array[0].split('');
  var second = array[1].split('');

  /*
  Loop through both arrays by using two for...of loops
  */
  var match = first.filter(function(f, i) {
    return second.indexOf(f) !== -1;
  });

  // Display results
  if (match) {
    result.innerHTML = `
The letter "${match[0]}" is the first match between both strings.`;
  } else {
    result.value = "There was no match."
  }
  return;
}

/* 
This is an onevent property registered to the input
If a user types into the input then clicks outside of input
the Event Handler ripZ() is called.
*/
str.onchange = ripZ;
```

```html
<input id='string'><button>GO</button><br>
<output id='result'></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input was "ab,ba", you sad that it should be return b so Code must be above in my openion :

```
function Ripetizione() { 
  //  var rip=document.getElementById("string").value;
  //  if (rip.indexOf(",")==-1){
  //      alert("Non c'è nessuna virgola");
  //      return;
  //  }

  //  var stringa1=rip.substr(0,rip.indexOf(","));
  //  var stringa2=rip.substr(rip.indexOf(",")+1,rip.length-(stringa1.length+1));
var stringa1="ab";
var stringa2="ba";

for(var i=0; i<stringa2.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<stringa1.length;j++){
        if(stringa2.charAt(i) === stringa1.charAt(j)){
            console.log(stringa2.charAt(i));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```